# How to hide row in GridView if certain column is empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a `GridView` that displays some information about a job and one of the options in the `GridView` is to select a reason. If a reason isn't selected then I don't want to display that row in the `GridView`. How do I check if there is a value in the Reason column, and if its empty how do I hide that row?

```
private GridView BuildDebriefGridView()
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        //gv.RowDataBound +=
        gv.Columns.Add(new BoundField { HeaderText = "Job No", DataField = "JobNo" });
        gv.Columns.Add(new BoundField { HeaderText = "Qty Rcvd", DataField = "QtyRcvd" });
        gv.Columns.Add(new BoundField { HeaderText = "Reason", DataField = "Reason" });
        gv.Columns.Add(new BoundField { HeaderText = "Comment", DataField = "Comment" });
        gv.Attributes.Add("style", "width:100%");

        return gv;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just change your query to not get rows without the value ? It would be much more simple.

Comment: Use Gridview_RowDataBound Event ...

Comment: You should really avoid putting HTML attributes in your code like this. It's much better to do this with CSS.

Comment: @Shirish what do I need to add to Gridview_RowDataBound function? I added code to my question

Comment: check your logic for row hiding there is nothing else in gridview event....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            JobPieceSerialNo item = e.Row.DataItem as JobPieceSerialNo;
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Reason))
                {
                    e.Row.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: e.Row.Visible=false worked for me.. Works like magic! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try following;

```
private void gvTransportListResults_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.Cells["Reason"].Text == "") 
        e.Row.Visible = false;
 }
```

Or if it is a checkbox

```
private void gvTransportListResults_RowDataBound(Object sender,   GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if(((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("YourCheckboxID")).Checked == false) 
        e.Row.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: That causes the error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments Error 36 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'`

Comment: Make sure you are passing right ID to FindControl method

Answer (score 1):

Using [GridView_RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event you can achieve this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[ReasonCellNumber].Text == "Reason")
        {
            e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error `DataBinding: 'BaseClasses.JobsClasses.Job' does not contain a property with the name 'Reason'.`

Comment: The error is self explanatory really.. it's telling you there's no property named `Reason`. See my updated answer. you can change it accordingly.. Please note you need to pass in the correct cell number for the `Reason` cell i.e. `1`